# port forwording using iptables on centos7

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I am using Centos7 in my physical server with public address and I have guest machine running on KVM environment with private IP address 192.168.122.2 I need to install httpd in the guest machine and redirect the traffic from the public IP address to the private adress 192.168.12.2.I tried:  `iptables -t Nat -A PREROUTING -I em1 -p TCP --deport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.2:80` where: em1 is my network interface in the physical machine, but it is not working.the forwording is actived and the command iptables -nvL return:

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 12 packets, 720 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
7   420 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.2        tcp dpt:80

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 406 packets, 59695 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ruleset is missing the stateful part allowing the return path for incoming traffic. Without it, TCP SYN packets are accepted from remote (as witnessed with the packet counters: 7) but reply packets (starting with TCP SYN-ACK) from inside to the original remote source most probably get dropped by the default policy DROP rule (as seen with the 12 dropped packets, probably replies plus a few retries).

Insert the stateful rules like this as the two first rules in the natural order by specifying their position:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
```

The second rule (`... --ctstate INVALID -j DROP`) should be used too especially [if later, some rules REJECT packets](https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/commit/?id=63291783a1a264b0d44606442f38435a5ac362c6) rather than just DROP them.

If that's not enough to solve your problem, you should add the output of this command in the question so I can try and help further:

```
iptables-save -c
```

[`iptables-save`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables-save.8.html), contrary to `iptables -nvL` produces a complete and *reproducible* (using `iptables-restore`) ruleset.

Please also note that:

- the NAT table is used with `-t nat` and not `-t Nat`.
- [indiscriminately dropping ICMP packets can create connectivity issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery#Problems) especially when there's a tunnel somewhere along the path. Though dropping *outgoing* ICMP might not be cause of such problems.